# Hide pagination from the blade when there is no record available in search results-Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

In my Laravel based application, I'm displaying the data from DB.

This is my controller function.

```
public function index(Request $request)

    {

        if($request->ajax()){
            
            
            $data = User::orderBy('id','DESC')
            ->where('role_id','=','3')
            ->where(function($query)use($request){
            $query->where('email','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%");
            $query->orwhere('first_name','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%");
            $query->orwhere('last_name','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%");
            })->paginate(12);

            return view('admins.participants.results',compact('data'))

                ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 12 );
        }

        else{

            $data = User::orderBy('id','DESC')->WHERE('role_id','=','3')->paginate(12);

            return view('admins.participants.index',compact('data'))

                ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 12 );

        }
        

    }
```

As you can see, I'm trying to display some search results.

Now my problem is the above-mentioned code works fine but once I search for something that, not available in my DB it still shows me the pagination with empty results...

On my blade I have following,

```
@if(!$data->isEmpty())

        {!! $data->render() !!}

    @else

    <p></p>
    
    @endif
```

How can I remove the pagination (next previous buttons and the numbers) when there are no results...

Answer (score 0):

Hi @VeenaviAnutthara you can use the by default laravel pagination service provider functionalty use this one line on the top of the your AppServiceProvider class and put this line in the view blade file {!! $currencies->links() !!}